# How to change letters in python with a different way

Tags: python

I want to learn python and i thought changing letters without any module or library i tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
d=list('banana')
a=list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

for i in range:
    d[i]=a[i+2]
print d
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

I would be appreciated if you help me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am triying to rotate words like rot13 but manually not with a library function

Comment: `for i in range:` is wrong - range(len(d))

Comment: what is the expected output here?

Comment: ('aabbcc') --> ('ddeeff') This is the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [63]: d=list('aabbcc')

In [64]: a='a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z'.split(",")

In [65]: for i,x in enumerate(d):
    d[i]=a[(a.index(x)+3)%26]

In [66]: d
Out[66]: ['d', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f']
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to specify parameters for [range function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
d=list('banana')
a=list('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z')

for i in range(len(d)):
    d[i]=a[i+2]
print d
```

From python documentation:

> range(start, stop[, step]) This is a versatile function to create
>   lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is most often used in for
>   loops. The arguments must be plain integers. If the step argument is
>   omitted, it defaults to 1. If the start argument is omitted, it
>   defaults to 0. The full form returns a list of plain integers [start,
>   start + step, start + 2 * step, ...]. If step is positive, the last
>   element is the largest start + i * step less than stop; if step is
>   negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater
>   than stop. step must not be zero (or else ValueError is raised).
>   Example:

```
>>>
>>> range(10) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1, 11) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> range(0, 30, 5)
```

Edit per request:

```
d = list('banana')
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
mappings = dict((ch, a[idx+2]) for idx, ch in enumerate(set(d)))

for idx in range(len(d)):
    d[idx] = mappings[d[idx]]
#OR:
d = [mappings[d[idx]] for idx in range(len(d))]

print d
```

Comment: However, with d=list('aabbcc') it outputs 'cdefgh' but should be 'ddeeff'. I cannot see where is the problem

Comment: added sample - not the best one but it should word

Answer (score 1):

string.translate is ideal for this ... Im not sure if that counts as a library ...

```
>>> import string
>>> tab = string.maketrans("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","mnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghi
jkl")
>>> print "hello".translate(tab)
tqxxa
```

alternativly

```
>>> print  "".join([chr(ord(c)+13) if ord(c) + 13 < ord('z') else chr(ord('a')+(ord(c)+13)%ord('z')) for c in "hello"])
'uryyc'
```

Comment: Can't i do that without any  library this is my issue

Comment: note the second solution will only work for lower case characters ... upper case will be left as an excersize for you (also this is a shift of 13)